# Verilog Array Walkthrough

Tags: verilog

I am just starting Verilog, and with little to no direction.  I have been trying to build an 4 bit array that I want to walk through turning on and then off each of my LED's in order.  I want them to go from 0-3, 7-4 and start over.  I haven't set up my loops yet, however I want to see if I'm at least going in the right direction.

```
// 4 bit oscillating LED pattern
module count_osc (rstn, osc_clk, clk, LED);

input   rstn;
output  osc_clk;
output  clk;
output  [7:0] LED;
reg     [22:0]c_delay;

genvar i;
genvar j;

GSR GSR_INST (.GSR(rstn));          // Reset occurs when argument is active low.
OSCC OSCC_1 (.OSC(osc_clk));

generate
        for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1) begin : LED_loop
            assign LED[i] = (clk);

            for (j=4; j<8; j=j+1) begin : LED_loop_2    
                assign LED[j] = (~clk); 
            end
        end
endgenerate
//  The c_delay counter is used to slow down the internal oscillator (OSC) output
//  to a rate of approximately 0.5 Hz
always @(posedge osc_clk or negedge rstn)
     begin
      if (~rstn)
           c_delay <= 32'h0000;
          else
           c_delay <= c_delay + 1;
      end
assign  clk = c_delay[22];

endmodule
```

Comment: When writing it out, do you mean turn on and off each LED individually?  I'm not sure how to do that and have it repeat in an infinite loop, that's why I wanted to try a for loop.  I am so used to C++ and some assembly language that loops feel safe, however I do see your point about the debugging problem, I'm experiencing that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few misconceptions about verilog here, which are quite common for programmers coming from more procedural languages.

If your not aware Verilog describes hardware and therefore everything can happen in parallel, we do not procedurally start at the top and work our way through lines of code. Every `initial` and `always` blocks are running at the same time.

`assign` should be used outside of loops and it is a continuos assignment, ie combinatorial logic.

`generate` is used for parameterising hardware instances, you should not need this on basic examples. NB it also means that the hardware you describe can be quite tricky to understand.

With that in mind you may realise that this block:

```
generate
    for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1) begin : LED_loop
        assign LED[i] = (clk);

        for (j=4; j<8; j=j+1) begin : LED_loop_2    
            assign LED[j] = (~clk); 
        end
    end
endgenerate
```

Does not mean much, the first section is:

```
assign LED[0] = (clk);
assign LED[1] = (clk);
assign LED[2] = (clk);
assign LED[3] = (clk);
```

The second for loop is inside the first but only uses the second variable essentially overwriting the same statements 4 times:

```
assign LED[4] = (~clk); 
assign LED[5] = (~clk); 
assign LED[6] = (~clk);
assign LED[7] = (~clk);
```

When suggesting you write out what you want I was implying you write out the above instead of using generates.

**Solution**
I am not sure of the exact sequence you want from your question as you refer to a 4 bit array but uses 8 elements for the LED.

I think this might be a good place to practice creating a FSM (Finite state machine).

```
reg [2:0] state;
reg [2:0] nextstate;

always @(posedge clk or negede rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    state <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    state<= nextstate;
  end
end

//Next state logic (keeping it simple)
always @* begin
    nextstate = state +1;
end

//Output logic
always @* begin
  case(state)
    3'd0 : LED = 'b0000_0000; //Binary makes sense as we can see the LED pattern
    3'd1 : LED = 'b0000_0001;
    3'd2 : LED = 'b0000_0011;
    3'd3 : LED = 'b0000_0111;
    3'd4 : LED = 'b0000_1111;
    3'd5 : LED = 'b0000_0111; 
    3'd6 : LED = 'b0000_0011;
    3'd7 : LED = 'b0000_0001;
    default : LED = 'b0000_0000; //Default unreachable if we completed the case
  endcase
end
```

I do not think this completes the sequence your trying to do but it should give enough of an understanding to complete the sequence yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I feel the working in parallel was throwing me off big time.  I'm so used to objects and ordered operation that this is a whole new world to me.  I plan on doing a lot of this so I need to understand syntax, declarations, and the only way I know how to do that is by correlating each language to one another.  This is probably the wrong way to do that, but your example will help me relate to this new language at least in an abstract.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sagebrushwilly, no problem glad to help. If this did answer the question it would great if you could accept it, so others know it is answered. NB good questions with a clear question or issues and some code to show what you have tried should get good responses.